# Can't extend partition on xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

I have xubuntu remix and xubuntu dual booted. How do I remove xubuntu and fix boot?

Can I also extend xubuntu remix to take whole disc?

screenshot of gparted
[image]

Comment: add the screenshot of gparted showing your partitions

Comment: How do i add one

Comment: take a screenshot upload the image to http://imgur.com/  and past the link here

Comment: http://imgur.com/aw7FGGF

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to extend Xubuntu remix to take the whole disk. Dont forget to **backup** your data before starting..

**Resize and extend partitions**

- First boot into a live ubuntu, unmount all the partitions
- using gparted delete the partation containing xubuntu (in your case sda6,sda5,and sda2)
- now right click in the partition containing xubuntu remix(sda1) and select resize/move
- then drag the end of partition to take all the space

**Install grub**

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX(sda)
```

where XXX is the disk where xubuntu remix is installed (eg. sda,sdb...etc)

Or use `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Backup before change partitions.

Comment: It wont let me once i delete partition. Wont extend

Comment: I cant the slider is the whole way up,

Comment: http://imgur.com/VH15Djk

Comment: ok now swapoff the sda5 partition, and delete the sda2 and then unmount sda1 , nowyou should be able to resize your sda1 partition

Comment: Worked cant install grub though- also 64bit

Comment: http://m.imgur.com/RlMKMR9

Comment: http://m.imgur.com/iUYLtmo -      thats on the os on /sda1, the other is live usb

Comment: if xubuntu boots fine no need to fix grub...

Comment: Cant use sudo update-grub on my live elementary os usb

Comment: use ubuntu live usb

Answer (score 0):

You can use parted or gparted utilities to extend Xubuntu remix to the whole disc if the partitions are adjacent. To do this delete the Xubuntu partition and then extend the other one over the unallocated space and apply the changes.
Ragarding the boot loader (I assume grub) you can reinstall it by running

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

where XXX is you whole disk e.g. sda, sdb etc.